# Can a smooth matrix function $M_{ij}(t)$ change rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-functions

Let $M_{ij}(t)$ be smooth functions of a real parameter $t$, such that $\mathbb M(t) = (M_{ij}(t))$ is a $n\times m$ real matrix. By smooth I mean that $M_{ij}(t)$ is continuous and differentiable.

Suppose $\mathbb M(t)$ is of deficient rank, $r < m,n$ for some interval of values $t \in [t_0,t_1]$. Provided $\mathbb M(t)$ is always smooth in its domain, can can the rank $r(t)$ change?

My puzzlement arises from the fact that $r(t)$, being discrete, will necessarily jump discontinuously. I'm not sure if this can be reconciled with the smoothness of $M_{ij}(t)$. My intuition is that a change of rank implies some "discontinuity" of $M_{ij}(t)$, but maybe at a higher-order derivative?

Comment: Consider any [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) as a function that has a $1 \times 1$ matrix as its value. The function is smooth but the rank changes from $0$ to $1$ back to $0$.

Comment: How about a zero $3 \times 3$ matrix but $M_{1,1}(t) = t$?

Comment: @a06e The rank is not a continuous function (but it is lower semi-continuous), so discontinuity in the rank doesn't imply discontinuity in $M(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, that's all I wanted. @BenGrossmann I do not understand your second argument though, about the rank being semi-continuous. How's is this relevant?

Comment: @a The source of your puzzlement is that $r(t)$ jumps, even when $M(t)$ varies smoothly. My answer to this conundrum is $r(t)$ is able to change discontinuously because it is not a continuous function. The discontinuity doesn't (necessarily) come from $M(t)$, it comes (or can come) from the rank function itself.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see, you view $r(t) = r(M(t))$ as a function composition, and then $r(M)$ is the discontinuous one. Thanks that's a helpful comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible for the rank to change. Consider the smooth matrix-valued function
$$ \mathbf M:\mathbb R\to {}^1_1 \mathbb R^2 \\ \mathbf{M}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}t & t^2 \\ \sqrt{|t|}& |t|^3\end{bmatrix}$$
$\mathbf M(-1), \mathbf M(1)$ are of rank one and $\mathbf M(0)$ is of rank zero but $\mathbf M(t)$ is of rank two for $t\notin \{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Surely we say $\mathbf M (0)$ has rank $0$?

Comment: $\mathbf M(t)$ never has rank 2 because it has two identical rows

Comment: @BenGrossmann Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Some geometric intuition might help here. The space of all matrices is simply $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$, the Euclidean space. A part of it has rank $0$, another part has rank $1$, etc. There's nothing whatsoever that stops you from moving from one part to another, since it's just a plain flat space. The problem is the rank function is discontinuous, so you can't expect any smoothness to carry over.

Comment: Thanks, this is also helpful. By the way, is there some more structure to these rank 0, rank 1, ... "surfaces" in $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$? rank 1 is $m+n$-dimensional, rank 2 is $2m+2n-2$-dimensional (?), etc. Has this been studied before?

Comment: @a06e The part of rank less than $k$ is described by an algebraic system of equations. And you can easily determine the dimension there. The part with rank *exactly* $k$ is just one set minus another. It has connections with the Grassmannian etc.