# Is Rank($X$) a smooth function where $X$ is a $m \times n$ matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Is the function$$f:\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$ defined by
$$f(X)=\text{rank}(X),$$ a smooth function?

The context of this question is that I was trying to prove $\mathbb{R}^{m,n}_r$, a set of $m\times n$ matrices with rank equal to r, is an embedded manifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m,n}$. The first thing is to find a local defining **smooth** function $f(x)$, and I tried to use $f(x)=\text{rank}(X)-r$ as the local defining function.

Comment: Nope. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855806/can-a-smooth-matrix-function-m-ijt-change-rank/4855810#4855810

Comment: Perhaps your Question asks if the function $\operatorname{rank} X$ is continuous (as a map from $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ to $\mathbb N$).  The term *smooth* needs qualification if you are asking from more than that, e.g. differentiability or [Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).  Unfortunately your problem statement lacks even the modicum of *context* that would help Readers understand what meaning is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & \epsilon\end{bmatrix}$ as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$. The rank is $2$ for all $\epsilon>0$ but in the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ it is $1$

Answer (score 3):

No it is not even continuous since its image is not connected.

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete you would need to ensure that it is constant to be connected but $\operatorname{rank}(0) = 0 \neq \operatorname{rank}(E_{1,1}) = 1$